# give an example of a matrix $Q$ that has orthonormal columns but $QQ^T\ne I$

Tags: linear-algebra, orthonormal

I need to give an example of a matrix $Q$ that has orthonormal columns but $QQ^T\ne I$. So my thinking is the following:

$ Q =   
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0  
\\0 & 1
\\0 &0  
\end{bmatrix} $ I know that these columns are orthonormal but what does $I$ refer to?

Comment: $I $ is identity matrix

Comment: $I$ is the identity matrix of appropriate dimension.

Comment: @learnmore perfect thanks so much

Comment: so then these would work perfect since $QQ^T \ne I$

Comment: Yes that would work